# UIToolbar offset - black strip appearing

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

So here's my Swift code (AppDelegate.swift):

```
var window: UIWindow?
var rootViewController :UIViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 7) {
        //yes, I'm using a newer iOS - greater/equal to iOS 7
        rootViewController  = Login(nibName:"Login",bundle:nil)
        let x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        let frame = CGRectMake(0,20,x,y)
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

        window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()                

        //window!.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,window!.frame.size.width,window!.frame.size.height-20);
     }

     return true
}
```

I'm trying to offset the screen down by 20px.

Here's what my emulator looks like using the above code (wrong!):

[image]

Here's what it looks like if I do nothing (wrong!):

[image]

Here's what I want it to look like!

[image]

I've been at this for HOURS.

I want a robust and manageable way to shift everything down by 20px.

(p.s. I'm **not** using storyboards)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
        rootViewController  = Login(nibName:"Login",bundle:nil)

        if ((UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8) {
            //For iOS 8
            rootViewController?.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
            rootViewController?.definesPresentationContext = true;
            rootViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
        }else{
            //For iOS 7
            rootViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
        }
        let x = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let y = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, y)
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)
        window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```